# ListView - ClickListener with custom adapter removes item touch highlight

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I wrote a custom adapter for my listview. Now it contains different kinds of items (let's say titles and text).

Titles don't need to have actions attached so I don't want to see the item touch highlight when clicking on it. However, texts may perform an action which is different for each text. Here's the code of my custom adapter.

```
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        MyItemHolder myItemHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
             //...;
            convertView.setTag(myItemHolder);
        } else {
            myItemHolder = (MyItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        MyItem myItem = myItems.get(position);
        if (myItem.isTitle()) {
            convertView.setOnClickListener(null);
        } else {            
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //do nothing at the moment
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

As you can see, settings a null click listener disable the list's item click animation, so I'm fine with that. However when setting an empty click listener, it also removes this animation (in fact calling `setOnClickListener` removes the animation).

If it can help here's my list view xml :

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
```

How can I let the default item click animation in my listview for items which are not title inside my adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You should use OnItemClickListener instead of onclick listener on each list item. To disable the onClick effect on "title" type item, you can use isEnabled method in your adapter class.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.isEnabled(position);
}
```

Comment: Yes now I don't need to set a null click listener for title, so that's seems less hacky. However as each text has a specific listener, I would like to keep the logic in the adapter instead of moving it to my fragment class. Don't you know why setting the click listener disable this animation? Is there any way to set the click listener on my item directly?